# How to fix "TypeError: message.member.hasPermission is not a function" in Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I was making Permissions Handler and I get the error "TypeError: message.member.hasPermission is not a function". What's my mistake?

```
        const validPermissions = [
        "CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE",
        "KICK_MEMBERS",
        "BAN_MEMBERS",
        "ADMINISTRATOR",
        "MANAGE_CHANNELS",
        "MANAGE_GUILD",
    ]

    if(command.permissions.length){
        let invalidPerms = []
        for(const perm of command.permissions){
          if(!validPermissions.includes(perm)){
            return console.log(`Invalid Permissions ${perm}`);
          }
          if(!message.member.hasPermission(perm)){
            invalidPerms.push(perm);
          }
        }
        if (invalidPerms.length){
          return message.channel.send(`Missing Permissions: \`${invalidPerms}\``);
        }
```

Comment: The console seems to be clear here : `message.member.hasPermission is not a function`. Check what exactly is `message.member.hasPermission` (or post it here)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The documentation of `discord.js` says in the change log [GuildMember#hasPermission](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#guildmember-haspermission): `…The GuildMember#hasPermission shortcut/helper method has been removed.…` are you sure that `hasPermission` exists for `member` for the version of `discord.js` you use?

Comment: Thanks! All the same, I rarely look in the documentation in vain

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`message.member.hasPermission()` has been [removed](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#guildchannel) in djs v13, you need to use `message.member.permissions.has()` now!